# Unit tests for basic_string equivalent

Tags: c++, string, testing, stdstring

I am finishing development of a customized string class. It is, of course, intended to be equivalent to basic_string with the internal storage customized for its intended purpose. I am looking for a test harness that will put it through the paces with respect to the C++ standard. I have seen that libstdc++ has a testsuite. However, I have been unable to find it.

Comment: Why not use `char_traits` and locales with `basic_string` instead of rewriting all of string yourself?

Comment: What do you mean by "internal storage customized for its intended purpose"?  `char_traits` won't help you for most of the ways I interpret that phrase, but `allocator` might.

Comment: We use a custom version of basic_string already. There are reasons why-some good, some probably bad. Nonetheless, it works very well and provides useful benefits. In any case, class allows for different "internal storage models" for the string, e.g., the common simple vector<char_type>, the small string optimization as some Microsoft version does, a "copy on write" optimization, or, in my case, what is essentially a linked list of vector<char_type>. basic_string is/should be agnostic to all of this. My case required custom iterators and it is really these iterators that I want to test.

Comment: @Hamp And note that in C++11 they finally require that the storage be contiguous as it is for vector, so most of your options won't technically be conforming anymore (which doesn't mean you can't still use them).

Answer (score 1):

Licensing issues and all not withstanding you can always use the libc++ [test cases for strings](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/test/strings/). The test system is based on CMake and really easy to understand/integrate.

Comment: Thanks. This is the kind of thing I am looking for. I will check the license for usability.